# How to get a UITOUCH from a tapped location in uiscrollview?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uitouch

I have a UIScrollView .In that i have one ImageView.

I want to get UITOUCH point .

i know i can get location by

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
   CGPoint touchPoint = [tapRecognizer locationInView: _tileMap]
}
```

But i want uitouch on image.

PLease help me.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [tapRecognizer locationInView: tapRecognizer.view]
}
```

AND set image view `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`

```
     UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    image.frame = CGRectMake(55, 30, 50, 40);
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    self.view.tag =10;
    image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [image addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```